# TortoiseSVN shows PPT files as modifed upon open-close

Tags: tortoisesvn, ms-office, powerpoint

I am sure some of you must have seen this behavior although I could not find an existing thread on SO regarding this very specific issue and hence posting it with hope that experts on SO might have an answer.

I noticed that whenever MS PPT files are opened and closed from a TSVN Working Copy, TSVN marks it as modified. For example, I check out a SVN repo which has PPT files stored in it. Now even if I simply open and close the PPT file (without making a SINGLE edit) from my local WC, TSVN will mark it as modified (red exclamation mark).

It gets very annoying after some time as it gets hard to track (without using some kind of diff tool) whether the red exclamation mark is because I actually changed the content in the file or if it is simply because I opened and closed the file at some point of time.

SVN Server: 1.4.6 (r28521)
TSVN Client: 1.7.6, Build 22632 - 64 Bit , 2012/03/08 18:29:39
MS Office: Office 2010 (Standard)

Comment: If you don't save your document in PPT the file is not modified. Have you checked that there is no add-in installed that automatically saves the file?

Comment: If SVN shows that the file was modified -- it was modified. Why was it modified is the other question. Check the add-ins.

Comment: I don't think it is an add-on issue. I just had one add-on installed (Adobe PDF maker) and even after disabling it I see the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem reported by people who use repositories.  Unfortunately, it's just something that PPT does.  MS is aware of it, has been for several versions, doesn't seem to consider it a big enough problem to bother with (or fixing it would interfere with other features they consider more important, perhaps).

Comment: It is also surprising that MS Office does this for PPT and XLS files but not for DOC files. With DOC files, opening and closing them is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

MS Office sometimes saves files automaticaly.I think from SVN point of view, you can set read-only attribute as workaround, or open files in read only mode from Powerpoint.Then it should not change modify timestamp.

Comment: Thinking about your comment regarding timestamp, do you mean Last Modified date? I just checked the properties of one of such file which TSVN shows as modified and the Last Modified date on that file is about 2 months ago which is accurate as I recall modifying that file (and by that I mean making "edits" on slides) that file around that time. Also, I am aware of the opening file in read-only mode workaround but it is a bit of pain to do that.

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint automatically saves the presentation preview image when you open the presentation file, even if you do not save it manually. To avoid this you have to open the file, go to file properties dialog and uncheck "Save preview picture" checkbox. Now you presentation file will stay unchanged unless you save it by yourself.